# ModuleNotFoundError when running Python script from Supervisor

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, supervisord

I use supervisor to start python script from my package. 
When I try to start the process from supervisor it spawns error: `Exited too quickly (process log may have details)`. But everything alright when running this script from terminal:

```
cd /var/www/html/MyProject
source venv/bin/activate
python src/main.py
```

Supervisor process configuration:

```
[program:MyProject]
directory=/var/www/html/MyProject/
command=/var/www/html/MyProject/venv/bin/python src/main.py
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile = /var/www/html/MyProject/logs/myproject_testing-out.txt
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 3MB
stdout_logfile_backups = 3
stderr_logfile = /var/www/html/MyProject/logs/myproject_testing-err.txt
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 3MB
stderr_logfile_backups = 3
```

Error in logfile (`/var/www/html/MyProject/logs/myproject_testing-err.txt`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import src.config as config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no module named `src`. Maybe you should add the project root to the python import path? This can be done by setting environment variables in the supervisor config.
 `environment=PYTHONPATH=/var/www/html/MyProject/`

Comment: @HåkenLid Added it to MyProject supervisor config but it didnt affected, still spawns that error.

Answer (score 0):

If both `main.py` and `config.py` or `config` package are in `src` you don't need to import config like that, you can just import it like this:

```
import config
```

If you want to import it from `src` like you do maybe you are missing an `__init__.py` file in that folder to make it a package, though having the source folder as a package doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I made `src` a package for alembic because I need to import my models metadata  file to alembic env.py: `target_metadata = src.base.Base.metadata`. Alembic files are outside `src` directory, thats why I did that.